# C#: How to get header from WCF response?

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to access a third party WCF service from C#. It has a login method which only returns true or false as result, but if login is successful, it returns a cookie (using "Set-Cookie" header).

How can I get the cookie? I found no way to access the full response. Is there an event I can attach a handler to? Message Interceptors only show the message, not the headers.

The code so far:

```
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.NetHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://host.com/service/webservice.svc");
var svc = new WebSvc.ServiceHostClient(binding, address);     
var res = svc.Login("username", Base64Encode("secret"));
```

`res` is true on successful login => how to get the cookie from the response?

Answer (score 0):

Client message inspectors should be used ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client)).

You need to inspect `reply` parameter of the `AfterReceiveReply` method. The `reply.Header` is the collection of all headers in the reply.

Comment: I have tried this: the reply.Header contains the headers of the SOAP response, not the HTTP response. The headers are "{<Action d1p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"[...]</Action>}" and "{<RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:[...]</RelatesTo>}". HTTP headers would be "Content-Type", "Set-Cookie" and so on.

Comment: In the meantime, I have found a workaround: Because I only need to call one method of the service, it is possible to work without the WCF client. I used Fiddler to get the request which the WCF client is sending. Then I copied the XML into a variable and use a WebRequest to send it. For binary encoding I'm using https://github.com/GDSSecurity/WCF-Binary-SOAP-Plug-In/blob/master/burp_wcf_plugin/src/NBFS.cs. Not elegant, but works.